# Data Visualisation: Drawing heatmap using latitude, longitude of 100.000 elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, data-visualization

I have a big array with 100.000 elements. The elements represent the occurrence of crimes in US cities. Each element has a latitude and a longitude.

I want to draw those crimes on a canvas to make a data visualisation in form of a heatmap but since the coordinates of the crimes are so close to each other I'm really struggling with the scaling and don't really have an idea how to approach this.

The array looks like this:

```
var nyc = 
    [{"city":"NYC","longitude":-73.935242,"latitude":40.730610},
    {"city":"NYC","longitude":-74.044502,"latitude":40.689247}]
```

And my code so far like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var lat;
var lon;

ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


for (var i = 0; i < nyc.length; i++) {
    lat = (nyc[i].latitude)*400-13200;
    lon = (nyc[i].longitude+200)*4;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.rect(lat, lon, 4, 4);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

How could I continue now?

Help is greatly appreciated!

NOTE: I don't think I need a map projection since I wan't to display the elements relativ in form of a heatmap thats has a square shape.

Comment: This is a complex problem, have you looked at any of the heat map libraries?. Else I would use some GPU/2D Canvas tricks to create the contour maps.Preprocess the data is where the work is. Provide abstracted detail levels (eg when zoomed out only process states) with grid based indexing eg NYC would be dataSet.grid[73][40] for quick data lookup. BTW you will need to use mercator projection which is simple to use and can be pre processed to give 2D map coords rather than lat/lon as Lat/Lon will create a distorted flat projection with line of lon curving in as you go north.

Comment: My bad on the projection was thinking back to front so statement is completely incorrect. sorry.